# Backbone-nested: Rendering nested elements

Tags: backbone.js

I am using the `Backbone-nested` plugin, declaring my `Models` as `Backbone.NestedModel.extend()` : https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested

This allows me to retrieve data as such: `this.model.get('tasks.title')`

The problem I am having is rendering each of the nested items. I can output 1 using `this.model.get('tasks[0].title')`.

However, if I write a loop to iterate over each of the nested, when `return this;` is called after the `render()` method for the `$el` to be appended back to the `Collection $el`, it fails.

**Question**

How can I write an efficient way for the nested elements to be rendered to the collection view?

**Collection View**

```
App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#taskList',

        initialize: function() {
            Event.on('tasks:show', this.show, this);
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(project) {
            console.log(project.toJSON());
            var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: project });
            this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
        },

        show: function(id) {
            var project = this.collection.get(id);
            var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: project });
            this.$el.html(taskView.render().el);
        }

    });
```

**The data (A project)**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "51497f8dc5c3e3ec28ce4571",
    "name": "First Project",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "title": "Second",
        "content": "Lots of content...",
        "deadline": "1-1-2011",
        "status": "in-progress",
        "_id": "51497f8d726694b230000002"
      },
      {
        "title": "Third",
        "content": "Lots of content...",
        "deadline": "1-1-2011",
        "status": "in-progress",
        "_id": "51497fa18aeb50c630000002"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to come across this question several times about displaying a nested layout.

There is a JavaScript library that sits on top of Backbone.js that reduces the amount of boiler plate code you have to write and they have a CompositeView that works best with nested collections. I've included the documentation and an article that discusses using it.

[Marionette CompositeView documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)

[Marionette CompositeView Article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)

[A similar question that I answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481666/nested-models-with-collection-of-itself-in-backbone-js/15489543#15489543)

Hope this helps.